# Como determinar si los valores de una lista de objetos es igual (true o false) que otra lista

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Buen dia, estoy tratando de validar si una lista de objetos es igual a la otra. osea necesito saber si o no lo es.

```
    var existe = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                        {
                            new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                                JMPMD_ModificadorID = 108,
                                JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                            },
                            new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                                JMPMD_ModificadorID = 109,
                                JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                            },
                            new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                                JMPMD_ModificadorID = 110,
                                JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                            },
           };




            var items = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                        {
                            new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                                JMPMD_ModificadorID = 108,
                                JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                            },
                            new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                                JMPMD_ModificadorID = 105,
                                JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                            },
                            new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                                JMPMD_ModificadorID = 110,
                                JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                            },
           };

        var valido = false;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            foreach (var ex in existe)
            {
                if (ex.JMPMD_ModificadorID == item.JMPMD_ModificadorID)
                {
                    valido = true;
                }
                else {
                    valido = false;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(valido);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Salida: true.
de alguna manera necesito saber si es igual o no. alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Iguales si contienen los mismos elementos sin importar el orden o el orden importa? En tu ejemplo hay un objeto que tiene un valor diferente en las listas 105 y 109.

Comment: igual si los modificadoresID son todos iguales, con haber una diferente en si no deberia ser igual la lista existe con items, el criterio es el modificador id, lo olvide comentar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La primer condición es que ambas listas tengan el mismo tamaño.

La segunda es que en la lista `items` debe haber un elemento con el mismo `JMPMD_ModificadorID` que la lista `existe`.

En la lista `existe` se aplica la función `All()` que devuelve verdadero si todos
los elementos de la lista cumplen la condición.

```
bool sonIguales = 
    existe.Count == items.Count
    && existe.All(e => items.Any(i => i.JMPMD_ModificadorID == e.JMPMD_ModificadorID));
```

Comment: Hombre! gran detalle que había pasado por alto, tienen que tener la misma cantidad de objetos !! like por eso

Answer (score 1):

Usando una sola instruccion;

```
List l = new()...
List l2 = new()...
l.Where(x => l2.Any(d => d==x)).ToList().Count()==l.Count()
```

**Explicacion:**
La idea sería utilizar el lenguaje de consulta linq integrado en c# para operar con listas:
Primeramente creamos una lista con los elementos de la primera lista que se encuentren en la segunda:

**x (aunque podria ser cualquier otro nombre)**: es el elemento que utilizamos para iterar
**Any**: permite obtener un booleano si la condicion existe:

```
l.Where(x => l2.Any(d => d==x))
```

Aquellos elementos(x) que aparezcan alguna vez(any) en la segunda lista(l2)

los agrupamos

```
.ToList()
```

Contamos la longitud de esta lista

```
.Count()==l.Count()
```

Si la longitud de la lista inicial , es igual que la lista de elementos que aparecen en la segunda lista significa que todos los elementos aparecen

Comment: Brillante! ¿Cómo funciona? ¿Qué puedo aprender de esto?

Comment: @CandidMoe A que te refieres?

Comment: La idea es que la respuesta le sea útil a muchos, no sólo al OP. Por ejemplo, podrías explicar el estilo y los conceptos claves de la solución, el cómo funciona. Hay una diferencia de nivel enorme entre el OP y tú. A él simplemente le parecerá magia.

Comment: De acuerdo @CandidMoe , he editado la respuesta incluyendo una explicación , si te ha sido útil agradezco que la puntues.

Comment: Quedo mucho mejor.